# Django user appears as if not logged in

Tags: django, authentication

I have created some seperate views and corresponding templates with django. They all extend a base.html template, and just now I have added some buttons to the header of base.html so I can navigate between the different views.

My site also has a user model implemented. In the header I make a quick check to see if a user is logged in. When it I display his / her name and when he / she isn't it shows a register and login link.

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p class="top-menu" style="font-size:17px">Logged in as: {{ request.user.name }} (<a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="top-menu">Logout</a>)</p>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'registration' %}" class="top-menu">Register</a> / <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="top-menu">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

Now my problem is that for all pages this actually works as expected, except for one. It's a page with a form(set) on it. The GET looks like this:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
        form_submission = SubmitForm()
        formset_authors = formset_factory(SubmitAuthorForm)

    c = { 'form_submission': form_submission, 'formset_authors': formset_authors }
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('journal_submit.html' ,c , RequestContext(request))
```

The weird thing is that when I add a login_required decorator it does let me pass. So it knows I'm logged in. I'm guessing that the user somehow isn't passed on correctly. Is this correct? and if so how can I do this (safely)?

Comment: if you use the django's `django.contrib.auth.context_processors`, you can leave  `request` of `request.user` out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

render_to_response was deprecated, and I assume your issues are with using `RequestContext`, instead you can just use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
return render(request, 'journal_submit.html', c)
```

Comment: Things can be so simple sometimes when you know the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DisneylandSC - No worries, you shouldn't need to update the context with the csrf either